# Find form value from control name in parameter

Tags: c#, string, variables, replace

I need to replace placeholders in an email message with values. The placeholder and form control name are in a custom list `<MailReplacements>`, this has, for example:

```
replacement.placeholder = "[UserName]",
replacement.formcontrol = "NameText.Text",
```

Since `[UserName]` is literally what I want to use, it works great in my `string.Replace`. However, how do I use the VALUE of `NameText.Text` in my string.replace? If I use:

```
message.replace(replacement.placeholder, replacement.formcontrol);
```

I understandably get a message where `[UserName]` is replaced with `NameText.Text`. How do I get it to replace with the value of `NameText.Text` (ie "Joe Blow")?

The `[UserName]` and `NameText.Text` association is from a custom configuration in `web.config`. So, I'm not purposely using `NameText.Text` as a string, I'm receiving it as a string.

I don't know how to turn that string into the value it represents.

Comment: replacement.formcontrol = NameText.Text   did you try removing the quotes around NameText.Text

Comment: Are you using [webforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I just found FindControl:

```
var StoredPlaceholders = (CustomConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MailPlaceholders");
 foreach (CustomConfigurationSection placeholder in StoredPlaceholders.SubSections["placeholder"])
            {
                MailReplacements.Add(new MailPlaceholder
                {
                    Placeholder = placeholder.Attributes["name"],
                    Formcontrol = placeholder.Attributes["form"]
                });
            }
            foreach (MailPlaceholder replacement in MailReplacements)
            {
                if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(replacement.Formcontrol))
                {
                    TextBox txt = RequestForm.FindControl(replacement.Formcontrol) as TextBox;
                    if (txt != null) replacement.ReplacementValue = txt.Text;
                }
            }
```

Comment: sorry, I should have been more explicit in my comment... The links I included were pointing you to FindControl...